Want to simplify using jquery to display some html in many files
I have jQuery in html files to display a tag line on the web page. I want to put a line of code in the header, so I don't have to copy the many lines of jQuery code. I'll attach a working copy of what I have. I want to load everything that is in the <script src.... thru the end of the footer.html  in one line of code in the head.
The Main html.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Dunlavy US Home Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css">

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script> 
$(function(){
$("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script> 

</head>
<body>
<h2>This is a sample of a copied bottom line of text using jquery.
<br>
It Works Good.
</h2>
<br>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>

Contents of the "footer.html" file.
<p>Copyright &copy; 1999-2024 . Professional Systems Industries, by 3d</p>


Do not use client side JS to add templated content to your pages, for 3 reasons, 1) it's adding unnecessary network requests 2) it's slow 3) it's ugly as it'll cause a FOUC. Do this server side instead, before the page is sent to the client

This works but you need to remove
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous"

or self hosting your jQuery file.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dunlavy US Home Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script>$(function(){ $("#footer").load("https://upnow-prod.ff45e40d1a1c8f7e7de4e976d0c9e555.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/d1ssYtCPdBd5hm6PO3SfNKbf51I2/aae7787d-9227-4e3f-884f-326b76ab2063?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=cdd12e35bbd220303957dc5603a4cc8e%2F20240409%2Fauto%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240409T211511Z&X-Amz-Expires=43200&X-Amz-Signature=caba9ce30122d0f283bbeb3901db8ace52bef74c680013295a978482a7a47a0f&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22footer.html%22"); });</script> 
  </head>
<body>
<h2>This is a sample of a copied bottom line of text using jquery.
<br>
It Works Good.
</h2>
<br>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>




Your suggestion works and simplifies my problem. Unfortunately, I am in a position with only knowledge I find with others help. Thank you for your suggestion, SKJ !

@Ddaved your welcome, you can validate my answer if u find it usefull

please tell me how to validate

@Ddaved you have button near up and down vote
